# Displaying a sorted list with ngFor without sorting the source in Angular2

Tags: angular, sql-order-by, ngfor

I have an array of appointments

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    appointments: IAppointment[];
    ...
```

And I pass the list to the list component

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <appointment-list [appointments]="appointments" [title]="'Aankomende afspraken'"></appointment-list>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <appointment-list [appointments]="appointments" [title]="'Ingecheckte afspraken'"></appointment-list>
</div>
```

In this list component I order the appointments using a pipe on the *ngFor

```
<tbody *ngFor="let appointment of appointments | orderBy : '-startTime'>
...
</tbody>
```

Please see image with the result (watch the difference in ordering!):
[image: image with the result (watch the difference in ordering!)]

The first component is ordered like it should, but the second component is ordered reversed?

- Why?
- Does the orderBy sort the source array?
- Or does it only display the array ordered?

I want to be able to dispay the components with the same source array and same ordering but with different filtering, that's why I display the component twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`| orderBy` is a pipe and and it depends on it's implementation if the original array is sorted and then returned or a new array instance containing the same elements is created by the pipe.